# Variable separable differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Without several combination trials is there an algorithm during check for solution  whether a differential equation has its variables amenable to being separated or not ?

Comment: As far as I remember, Lie groups could answer this question (at least in theory), but I'll wait till someone more experienced try to answer your question.

Comment: At least this http://euler.nmt.edu/~jstarret/05-649LieGroupODEFinalVersion.pdf might be useful.